# Running Xilinx Command line Tools - XST does not work

Tags: bash, xilinx, xilinx-ise, xilinx-edk

I'm currently working on a project that students can hand in their xilinx projects via e-mail and i will Synthesis, Place and Route and generate a bitstream which then should be uploaded to an FPGA.

So first things first. I installed the ISE Tools on my Linux machine and now i'm trying to run xilinx's commands from the command line. But when i'm trying to run xst it says:

```
-bash: /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/lin/xst: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have experience with creating scripts to automate the xilinx sythesis processes?
Appreciate any help :)

nablahero

Comment: Xilinx has a guide for command line tools. Have you sourced the settings64.sh file from `/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/`? There are also tools to support command line synthesis flows -> `xflow`.

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks a lot. Now i can start working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue - problem probably is you are starting 32bit version of binaries on 64bit system. Try:

`/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/bin/`**`lin64`**`/xst`